# Spark sqlContext Exception while doing action on Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting below error when doing count on the parquet file,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$MessageTypeBuilder.addFields([Lorg/apache/parquet/schema/Type;)Lorg/apache/parquet/schema/Types$GroupBuilder;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystReadSupport$.clipParquetSchema(CatalystReadSupport.scala:117)
```

Detailed error as below:
ERROR org.apache.spark.util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-4,5,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

```
org.apache.parquet.schema.Types$MessageTypeBuilder.addFields([Lorg/apache/parquet/schema/Type;)Lorg/apache/parquet/schema/Types$GroupBuilder;
    at 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystReadSupport$.clipParquetSchema(CatalystReadSupport.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystReadSupport.init(CatalystReadSupport.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.initialize(UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.java:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.tryInitialize(UnsafeRowParquetRecordReader.java:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Couldnt figure out the issue. the dataframe has schemas as expected. Can you anyone show me the direction here

Comment: Which version of spark you are using? are you using just spark on your  local system by downloading from spark's website? Did you specify schema while reading or just read like - spark.read.parquet("filepath")?

Comment: using spark1.6.11 and simply reading tthe parquet

Answer (score 0):

Parquet related jars will not be present under lib folder for spark 1.6.1.

Download the jar from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop-bundle/1.10.0). Unzip the downloaded folder and place the jar inside lib folder present within spark folder i.e $SPARK_HOME/lib.
This should solve your problem.